# Is there an ready-made solution to mark edited form fields?

Tags: theming, forms

When you edit something in text editor or IDE, you get visual feedback - star next to file name, bolded file name et cetera. That way you easily know what has been edited and what not.

Is there a ready made solution to introduce that to Drupal? Either system-wide or manually using Form API? It would make sense to see if any changes was made or not, especially if one opens dozen of nodes for updates and then sees some of them are already up to date and does not need a save (and associated boost cache clears).

In large setting forms, like permissions or Elysia Cron, it would help too.

The ideal would be to add some class to each field with value not equal it's default value, so the theme could deal with it using only CSS.

Anyone written it already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've only seen [Track Field Changes](https://drupal.org/project/track_field_changes), but that doesn't give immediate visual feedback.

**Edit:** I know you asked for something that was already out in the wild, but the following *might* be useful.

I guess you could write something custom *relatively* easily though using jQuery's [.change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event.

Something like the following I guess (code will need checking but it should be pretty near).

**JavaScript**

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.formFieldTracker = {
      attach: function(){
        $(input).change(function(){
          $(this).addClass('field-edited');
        }));
      }
    }
})(jQuery)
```

**Module**

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  // Only add the JavaScript on admin pages as defined by hook_admin_paths()
  if (path_is_admin(current_path())) {
    $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE');
    drupal_add_js($path . '/js/MYSCRIPT.js');
    $vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js();
  }
}
```

Then you could add whatever CSS you fancy afterwards:

```
.field-edited:after {
  content: 'Edited';
  display: inline-block;
  color: #F00;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: I'll try it, thank you. I think... if I'll wrap it into a module, I can post it on Drupal.org so it'll be ready for other users ;) If I will, I'll make sure to give you credit, if you'll do it feel free to make me test or maintain it.

Comment: I'm willing to take a look, but I won't be able to get on it today as I am swamped with client work.  If you put it up on d.o then I'm more than willing to bugfix/text :-)

Comment: Accepting as from first tests it seems it works.

Comment: Also, it's only really a starting point.  That code will select ALL `input` elements, which may be undesirable (you might want to omit `input[type="button"]` for example.)

Comment: It works?  I thought there was an error in my JS that I've just noticed :-o.  I'll fix the error and if it breaks then just edit it back ;-)

Comment: I know, I know, that's why I called what I did "first tests". Sub-fields of managed file are other big issue. I didn't do a copy-paste, just tested approach roughly in firebug. Seems I simply omitted your bug.

Comment: +1. Suppose you could match the value to the default-value of the input element to do a slightly more sophisticated approach. By the way there's a `:input` jquery pseudo selector which covers selects as well: `$(':input').not(':button')` hopefully should cover it?

Comment: @Beebee Good call. Almost covers it. `managed_file` is still tricky. I hope in 6 hours we can move to issue queue in my sandbox.